# React Native the module could not be found

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I run the project yesterday and it works very well. Today, when I run my RN project with `react-native run-ios` and I got module could not be found suddenly.

My project's React-native versions

```
react-native-cli: 2.0.1
react-native: 0.52.2
```

My project's watchman version

```
4.9.0
```

My Folder Structure

```
src
  components
  screens
  stores
  Config.js
```

The following is my **Config.js**

```
const host = "localhost:5000";
const proto = "http://";
const api = "/api";

const Config = {
  urls: {
    signin_start: proto + host + api + "/signin/start",
    signin_verify: proto + host + api + "/signin/verify",
  }
};

export default Config;
```

I use Config from `screens/signInStart.js` file like the following

```
import Config from "../Config";
```

And I got an error like the following

```
The module `../Config` could not be found
```

How can I fix? I already do clear react native cache by running the following command. But, still can't fix.

```
watchman watch-del-all && rm -rf $TMPDIR/react-* && rm -rf node_modules/ && npm cache clean && npm install && npm start -- --reset-cache
```

Comment: have You tried "npm run ios"  script: "ios": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js run-ios" ?

Answer (score 2):

After looking and debugging for a very long time, I finally solved my problem by one of react native [Github issue](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/4968).

- Delete the node_modules folder:
  `rm -rf node_modules && npm install`
- Reset packager cache: `rm -fr $TMPDIR/react-*`
- Clear watchman watches: `watchman watch-del-all`
- Recreate the project from scratch

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/4968